# Jackson xml serialization - how to write schema location

Tags: jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

If I marshal java classes (generated through xjc from a xsd schema) using jaxb I correctly get this

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.010 pain.013.001.10.xsd">
```

I get this result annotating root class with

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Document", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.10")
```

and setting Marshaller JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION property

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION,
          "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.010 pain.013.001.10.xsd");
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the same result with Jackson.
This is the class annotation

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.10")
```

and this the code fragment

```
XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
mapper.registerModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule());
mapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mapper.writeValue(out, document);
System.out.println(out);
```

But doing so the result is

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.013.001.10">
```

How can I get schema location written in the output like in the jaxb approach?

Many thanks